# duplicate an android display on a non pc, stand alone, powered display

Tags: screen

I haven't yet seen my exact question asked (but many close), so forgive me if it has been already answered. is it possible to duplicate an android display on a non pc, stand alone, powered display ? and if so, how ? and are there multiple ways ? thx

Comment: Please provide a few extra details about what display you are using and what device you're using if it's not a PC.

Comment: Same for your device. Some devices ship with different capabilities pre-installed. So the combination of devices is relevant here :)

Comment: Hello & thx. My phone is a HTC One M7. I don't have the display yet, but I would like to get one that can be connected directly to my phone via cable(?, which kind, ie mini hdmi ?) I understand there is software needed, but not sure which, to make it work in this manner. And would like to power the display off the 12V car outlet...if possible ? thx

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to accomplish this (assuming that your display has an HDMI input), you can use a Chromecast device or directly connect your phone using an HDMI cable (again assuming that your phone supports that.)

If the above options are not suitable for you, you can make use of a raspberry pi to act as a bridge between your phone and the display.

Please provide more details about your phone and the display.

Comment: Hello & thx. My phone is a HTC One M7. I don't have the display yet, but I would like to get one that can be connected directly to my phone via cable(?, which kind, ie mini hdmi ?) I understand there is software needed, but not sure which, to make it work in this manner. And would like to power the display off the 12V car outlet...if possible ? thx

Comment: anybody know how to make this setup work ? TIA